# Avoid a block of code to run during unit test using mokito

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito

***I am using Mokitio in android to run unit test cases.***
.

- What i am trying to do: There is a block of code in `onCreate` event
  of the activity
- I am trying not to run this block of code during Running Unit test
  cases and run it during app regularly.
- Is it possible to do something like that using `mokito` because mokito synchronizes for activity life cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution here is to change your design a bit. You should not think in terms of *code blocks*, but in terms of *functionality*.

The way of preventing that some x lines of code are run in a certain environment, but are not in some other context ... is by using proper OO means.

Meaning: first create an interface that describes the *functionality* of those lines of code we are talking about:

```
public interface DoTheFoo {
   public void foo(Bar bar);
}
```

Then you create a "production" implementation *DoTheFooImpl* of that interface (which as a side effect: you might be able to write proper unit tests for as well).

Finally: within your class that needs that functionality, use **dependency injection** to acquire an object providing the *DoTheFoo* interface. In your production environment, that would be a *DoTheFooImpl* object; but for your unit testing, you would simply create an mock for it - configured to do nothing upen calls to foo().

Of course that sounds like a bit of work; but the point is: currently, your design is somehow deficient. And instead  of trying to go for dirty hacks/workarounds, consider looking at your design to identify a more elegant way to resolve your problem.